# Why does my CoffeeScript program issue 'number is not a function' error?

Tags: coffeescript

In the program below the first two logs work fine.  I'm not doing anything new in the third and final log but somehow it crashes at runtime.  Where is the error in my script?  I have looked it over a large number of times and it seems like a fairly trivial modification of the proven working code above it.

```
sumSq = (n) -> ([0..n].map (i) -> i * i).reduce (a, b) -> a + b
sq = (n) -> n * n
sqSum = ((n) -> ([0..n].reduce (a, b) -> a + b))
console.log(sqSum 5)
console.log(sq(sqSum 5))
newSqSum = sq ((n) -> ([0..n].reduce (a, b) -> a + b))
console.log(newSqSum(5))
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

This is a function, not a number:

```
(n) -> ([0..n].reduce (a, b) -> a + b)
```

so when you say this:

```
newSqSum = sq ((n) -> ([0..n].reduce (a, b) -> a + b))
```

you're calling `sq` with a function as its argument. Then `sq` will try to multiply that function with itself and the result will be `NaN` because there is no sensible numeric representation of a function. And finally, your third `console.log` tries to call that `NaN` value as function and there's your error message.

Something of the form `fn1 fn2`, for functions `f1` and `f2`, is not a function composition, it is in fact the same as writing `fn1(fn2)` and that won't produce a new function unless `fn1` is explicitly constructed to return a function. If you want to compose the functions then I think you need to do it by hand:

```
newSqSum = (n) -> sq ((n) -> ([0..n].reduce (a, b) -> a + b)) n
# Or with less hate for the people maintaining your code:
newSqSum = (n) -> sq sqSum n
```